# где указать путь к старым проектам PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Переустановил PyCharm, но он не дал мне прописать путь к старой папке E:\Project Python, а там все проекты. Написал, что папка не пустая. Прописал в пустую, но не хочу файлы перекидывать из одной папки в другую. хотелось бы разобраться, где путь указать к проектам, чтоб он их подтянул

Answer (score 0):

Буквально полчаса назад столкнулся с похожей проблемой.

Мне помогло это:

В PyCharm дважды нажмите <kbd>L_Shift</kbd>  или нажмите на значок лупы сверху, в окне поиска введите: "Open..." - откроется выбор текущей директории.

Comment: я просто переустановил пай чарм а перед этим удалил в папке проекта 2 папки .idea и venv